# Constructor: this(variable) vs this.method(variable) vs super.metchod(variable) difference

Tags: java

While doing some Oracle mock exam test I've found something, that never got my attention before:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    public MyThread(String name) {
        // We can use any:
        super(name);
        super.setName(name);
        this.setName(name);
    }
}
```

All the ways are valid, first two of them are common, but the question is - is there any difference between them and the third one?

super(name); - invokes super class constructor

super.setName(name); - invokes super class setName method

this.setName(name); - uses inherited setName method, which invokes super class setName method (am I right) ?

Comment: As `Thread.setName` fortunately is `final` there is no difference. However with the default constructor a random String is allocated for the name, to be garbage collected in short time.

Answer (score 2):

If your `MyThread` class doesn't override `setName`, there's no difference between `super.setName(name);` and `this.setName(name);`, and both can be replaced by `setName(name);`.

I just checked - `setName` is final, so you can't override it. Therefore there's no difference between the two calls to `setName`.

Initializing the name via the constructor is slightly different. If you don't call the constructor with the name parameter (`super(name)`), the parameterless constructor (`super()`) will be called implicitly, and initialize the thread name to `Thread-xx`. Only after the call to `setName` the name would be changed to the name to pass to it.

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, `super` refers to the super class, while `this` refers to the current object as it is.

Here it depends on if the current class overrides something it has inherited.

In your case, if we have an own `setName()`, `this.setName()` takes "ours", if not, it takes the inherited one. `super.setName()` always takes the inherited one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, supose that you have the class A

```
public class A {
    protected method(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

and a class B

```
public class B extends A {
    public B(){
        super.method(); //This should print "A"
        this.method(); //This should print "B"
    }
    protected method(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

That's the difference.

Comment: Thanks, so this can be a tricky question if there is no @Override annotation and you could miss overriden method while looking into code :)